# AMPscript Format other than 24-hour/military time

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formula

I am trying to use a single DateTime field from my data extension and use a formula to split into two clauses, one for date ('l' format, working fine) and one for "hh:mm am/pm" ('hh:mm tt' format) time.

Unfortunately it appears, at least within preview and the resulting test send, that my test record which is at 10:00 PM is appearing as "22:00 PM" which is obviously not desirable. I feel like I am missing something obvious but [military/24-hour time is not documented in the developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm?search_text=24h) as far as I can see.

The email recipient is from a Lead record, and the sending user's locale is set to "English (US)".

`%%=FormatDate(Object__c:Date_Time__c, "l", "", "en-US")=%%`
`%%=FormatDate(Object__c:Date_Time__c, "", "hh:mm tt", "en-US")=%%`

and the resulting date/time:

[image: result]

I've tried `h`, `hh`, `H`, and `HH` and they all return the same format. Has anyone run into this before? Is there a format or setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your link, there's something that reads "This example uses the "s" short token to format the time value 18:30 as a 12-hour clock value in the specified format:..." Have you tried that one to force the time back to 12-hour?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm?search_text=24h

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Totally misread that. At the bottom of your link, there's something that reads "This example uses the "s" short token to format the time value 18:30 as a 12-hour clock value in the specified format:..." Have you tried that one to force the time back to 12-hour?

Comment: Well that's a revelation all in itself. I'm blown away that it is listed there without so much as a sub-heading! If you edit that into your answer I'll go ahead and accept. Thanks for pointing my eyes downward :P

Comment: `%%=FormatDate(Object__c:Date_Time__c, "", "s", "")=%%` displays `10:00 PM` perfectly. Thanks again!